# How to define dynamic ranges on Calc (or Excel)?

Tags: excel, range, libreoffice-calc

Let's say I have a Libreoffice.org Calc (maybe this goes for MS Excel too) object defined as the range `$Sheet1.$A$1:$A$4`.

I also have declared a constant with value 1. For this mockup purpose, let's call it `startingLine`.

Both objects are properly defined in the Define Names dialog (shortcut: Ctrl+F3).

What I would like to do is to turn the *lines* of the defined range into variables. In my mind, all it'd take would be to define it like this: `$Sheet1.$A$startingLine:$A$4`, but this doesn't work. :-/

I'm looking for a simple spreadsheet solution, unfortunately macros won't do it for me this time. A solution using R1C1 reference would be good enough, though. :)

Any help will be *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to use a version of this formula (excel)
`=CELL("contents",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",startingLine)))`
This gives you the contents of cell A1 where `startingLine` is a constant 1. Additionally, if we define `endingLine` as A, we can replace A in the formula:
`=CELL("contents",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(endingLine,startingLine)))`

To define a range for you might be `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$sheet1.$A$",startingLine,":$A$4"))`
for instance to sum (in excel) `=SUM((INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$A$",startingLine,":$A$4"))))` but I am unfamiliar with the defining ranges in libreoffice

Comment: That's perfect, Raystafarian! My formulas are a bit huge now, but at least it seems to be working flawlessly. I've been trying to do this for over a year, you're the man!

Comment: Instead of `INDIRECT()` you could also use `OFFSET()`: `OFFSET($Sheet1.$A$1, startingLine - 1, 0, 5-startingLine, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

To utilise the results of a list in LibreOffice calc as the definition for a secondary list the following works:

First lists defined in `DATA>DEFINE RANGE` e.g. "Breakfast", "Dinner" where each item is a list containing a number of lines and is collectively named as either "Breakfast" or "Dinner".
[detailed menu choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwXb6.png)

the definition of the list named "Breakfast" might include: Bacon, Beans, Eggs, Hash Brown, Mushrooms, etc... this list is best defined on a separate sheet.

If you want to select the menu choices from each list based on the selection of either "Breakfast" or "Dinner" you need a list defined in data>validity with those two options. Say this is defined in cell `A2`.
[Top level choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gjWI.png)

To connect the two detailed menu choices named either "Breakfast" or "Dinner" with the choice between either, use the formula:

```
=indirect(A2)
```

in say cell C2.

When you select a choice from your defined list in A2, the spreadsheet will now use the entry in cell A2 to provide the correct list of choices in cell C2.

I hope that makes sense - and a big thanks to Waldir Leoncio for the reminder!