# Dynamic data range references for charts

Tags: charts, openoffice-calc

I have an OpenOffice Calc spread sheet that I'm using to track some data. I have three charts made from the data. I periodically add more data to the spreadsheet. My current way to propagate this to the chart is to alter the data ranges manually of each chart. I'd like to automate this, or at least not have to redundantly change each chart separately.

My current idea was to do something like `$A$1:$A{$F$1}` for the ranges where `$F$1` holds the current last line. Unfortunately, OpenOffice doesn't recognize this, but I thought there might be a function or work around for it. I haven't been able to find one yet.

So, is there a way to execute my idea, or perhaps a better way to do it?

There is a very similar question to this, but the asker asked for many more features and the answer was to use something other than a spreadsheet. It was never answered whether this specific feature was possible.

Comment: Did you have a look at this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179051/how-to-define-dynamic-ranges-on-calc-or-excel

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what I wanted. Sorry I missed that!

Answer (score -1):

Also:

First method is to extend the range of the graph way down, with lots of empty space.
Second method is to include only one extra line of data in the graph and when you add data, always insert it above that line.